# Configuring Linux Second Monitor

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution

I have two identical monitors (Compaq CQ1859s, 1366x768). I just installed Ubuntu onto the computer with which these monitors are being used. Upon installation, one of the monitors had its type detected perfectly, however the second monitor was stuck at 1024x768.

I installed the Nvidia drivers and this allowed me to bump it up to 1360x768, however it bugs me greatly because the right monitor is that bit clearer than the left. Is there any way to assign the left monitor to use the same drivers as the right or anything?

`xrandr -q` Output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2726 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
VGA-0 connected 1366x768+1360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Please include the output of `xrandr -q`

Comment: I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/mJpwr9v6

Comment: I edited it in to your question. See [this question and answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47749/cannot-add-new-mode-in-xrandr-for-external-monitor) for what you require.