# HiDPI screen and scaling

Tags: nvidia, video, resolution, dpi, high-dpi

I recently got a new work laptop which has a native resolution of 3200x1800. It works great. I've been able to get things to be mostly the right size with KDE's display scaling... but it's not quite "right".

I experience several minor issues which add up to me looking for a solution:

1. Some applications I are old enough to not be HiDPI scaling aware. They are few, but they exist. I can manually force them to use larger fonts, but this doesn't cover all UI concerns.
2. I get minor graphical artifacts in some applications such as `konsole` or `kate`. They aren't show stoppers, just some minor cruft that's sort of "in between" the lines. (It looks like they are off by a slight amount in calculating the line height).
3. When doing development of graphical UIs, if I use layout tools on this laptop, things end up about twice as spaced out on non HiDPI screens.

So, I was hoping to find a reasonable solution. Personally, I don't **need** the system to have a resolution greater than 1920x1080, so my initial gut is to search for an option to have the system render at 1920x1080 and then upscale to the native 3200x1800 (or something effectively similar).

Is this, or similar, something that can be done? I feel like the hardware can do it because before my system enters graphical mode, the text mode is the expected "non-tiny" size. So it seems capable of being at lower resolutions despite my system not really offering them.

For reference, the video card is an nVidia Quadro K2100M

Thanks for any thoughts :-)

Comment: My display only shows 2500x..., but I have similar problems. The only hint I can give you is if you don't want to use your native resolution, you'll get best effects with half your resolution, 1600x900,because then 4 hardware pixels can simply be used to draw one pixel.

Comment: @JakobLenfers, yea integer scaling would obviously look the cleanest. Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to get it to offer that.

The KDE UI only shows 3200x1800 as an option.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that in your question. I doubt I'll be able to help you, but I bet output of `xrandr` would be useful.

Comment: If you don't mind trying command line, then use `xrandr` and `gtf` to create a new video mode and see if your monitor and video card accept it.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47756/162020

Comment: @infixed yea, i'll give that whirl.

Comment: I use `xdpyinfo` to get DPI information and select different Xresources files based on this information. This is useful for applications that use X resources, but each application or X library needs its own, separate configuration. In particular, `XtDefaultFont` can be set for libXt-based applications.